# Azure Yaml Pipeline KeyVault task does not grab whole connection string

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

KeyVault task does not grab the whole keyvault secret and I dont know how to grab it all out

Here is my connection string:

```
Server=test.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=test-azdb;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;ConnectRetryCount=20;ConnectRetryInterval=30
```

When I do `Write-Output $connectionString` - The following information is printed:

```
Server=test.database.windows.net
```

Here is how I am calling the keyvault secret

```
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azure_subscription_name)
      KeyVaultName: ${{parameters.database_credential_key_vault_name}}
      SecretsFilter: "lab--myname--connectionstring"
      RunAsPreJob: false
```

Comment: Is it possible that the full value is being fetched from key vault, but the pipeline is deliberately not logging the full value because it recognises it as a secret?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a line-break in your connection string, and that is why only part of it is coming out in the log?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I assumed that too but sadly its not. I can see in the logs that its failing because the password and username field is empty